# Viewing channels in Gimp

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors, gimp

I would love to be able to view channels as black to white in gimp, if I look at for example the green channel it will show the intensity from zero = black, to 1 = full green. In Photoshop it show from black to white when I have a single channel selected which in most cases is much more informative (especially when doing specularity and glossiness mapping in texture).

So right now if I deselect red and blue channel I see the image in green I would like to be able to see the content in the green channel and I would find it much easier to view it if it went from black to white.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can do that by simply selecting/deselecting RGB channels, but you can get what you need by going to `Colors > Components > Decompose`, selecting RBG as decomposing method and choose if you want the channels displayed as different images or as layers of a single one.

Once you have performed the operations that you require on the RBG layers, you can go to `Colors > Components > Recompose` to build back the full image.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works at least good enough. I noticed also that I can keep my original image, get a decomposed copy and work in layers, and when I recompose it updates my original so it makes for a pretty nice workflow. Huge thanks for that one!